# Multiple Lines in Excel, need a Formula to calculate diferences

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an inventory spread sheet.
There are 5700 rows all up to column "I".
These rows have part numbers in column "A".
Column "I" contains the cost of that part based on a quantity of parts listed elsewhere in the table.

With me so far?

Lets say Row "1" contains a part number 9FH-01010 and column "I" gives a dollar value based on other criteria, (number of parts BEFORE Inventory).
Row "2" would be the same with the exception that row "2" is based on the dollar value AFTER inventory.

Is there a formula that could identify like cells in column "A" and then calculate the difference in dollar value of "I" and then place that answer in column "J"?

Here's the kicker, there are some part numbers that have only 1 entry.

Example:

```
"A1" = 9FH01010     "I1" = 5000.00     "J1" = -2500.00     
"A2" = 9FH01010     "I2" = 2500.00

"A3" = 9FH20202     "I3" = 4300.00

"A4" = 9FH30303     "I4" = 2000.00     
"A5" = 9FH30303     "I5" = 4000.00     "J5" = 2000.00
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What I'm getting is that (1) in each row, there is a key in $A; there will either be exactly 1 following row with the same key, or zero rows.

Have a look at the 'IF' function. This is probably the easiest way to code the function:

IF $a is equal to $a, then compute $I - $I.

Something like this:

```
=IF($A2 = $A1, $I2 - $I1, ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

In column A of your database you have ID's for the products, but they can appear twice. One for each circumstance (AFTER and BEFORE). I advice you first to add a column to determine which one is which.

The following formula works only if each product appears twice ("after" and "before")

in a NEW column, next to I5 -for example in J5- TYPE:

=IF(VLOOKUP(A5,A$1:I4,9,)>0,I5-VLOOKUP(A5,A$1:I4,9,),"")

then copy J5 up and down through the whole column.

If you want to avoid errors (#N/A), you can do a larger formula with IFERROR function.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sample data, assuming your data is in range A1:I5700

You can enter the following formula in cell J1 and drag it down to apply across:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(I2:$I$5700,MATCH(A1,A2:$A$5700,0))-I1,"")
```

[image: solution]